# Convert CMSampleBuffer to AVAudioPCMBuffer to get live audio frequencies

Tags: ios, swift, audio-streaming

I am trying to read the frequencies values from a `CMSampleBuffer` returned by `captureOutput` of `AVCaptureAudioDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate`.

The idea is to create a `AVAudioPCMBuffer` so that then I can read its `floatChannelData`. But I am not sure how to pass the buffer to it.

I guess I could create it with:

```swift
public func captureOutput(_ output: AVCaptureOutput,
                              didOutput sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer,
                              from connection: AVCaptureConnection) {
guard let blockBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetDataBuffer(sampleBuffer) else {
  return
}
let length = CMBlockBufferGetDataLength(blockBuffer)

let audioFormat = AVAudioFormat(commonFormat: .pcmFormatFloat32, sampleRate: 44100, channels: 1, interleaved: false)
let pcmBuffer = AVAudioPCMBuffer(pcmFormat: audioFormat!, frameCapacity: AVAudioFrameCount(length))
pcmBuffer?.frameLength = pcmBuffer!.frameCapacity
```

But how could I fill its data?

Answer (score 1):

Something along these lines should help:

```
var asbd = CMSampleBufferGetFormatDescription(sampleBuffer)!.audioStreamBasicDescription!
var audioBufferList = AudioBufferList()
var blockBuffer : CMBlockBuffer?

CMSampleBufferGetAudioBufferListWithRetainedBlockBuffer(
    sampleBuffer,
    bufferListSizeNeededOut: nil,
    bufferListOut: &audioBufferList,
    bufferListSize: MemoryLayout<AudioBufferList>.size,
    blockBufferAllocator: nil,
    blockBufferMemoryAllocator: nil,
    flags: 0,
    blockBufferOut: &blockBuffer
)

let mBuffers = audioBufferList.mBuffers
let frameLength = AVAudioFrameCount(Int(mBuffers.mDataByteSize) / MemoryLayout<Float>.size)
let pcmBuffer = AVAudioPCMBuffer(pcmFormat: AVAudioFormat(streamDescription: &asbd)!, frameCapacity: frameLength)!
pcmBuffer.frameLength = frameLength
pcmBuffer.mutableAudioBufferList.pointee.mBuffers = mBuffers
pcmBuffer.mutableAudioBufferList.pointee.mNumberBuffers = 1
```

This seems to create a valid AVAudioPCMBuffer at the end of it inside a capture session. But it's at the wrong frame length for my use case right now, so need to do some further buffering.